# How to merge 3 matrices into 1 in opencv?

Tags: opencv, matrix, concatenation

I have three matrices, each of size `4x1`. I want to copy all of these matrices to another matrix of size `4x3` and call it `R`. Is there a smart way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use hconcat for horizontal concatenation. You can use it per matrix, e.g. hconcat( mat1, mat2, R ), or apply it directly on a vector or array of matrices.

Here's a sample code:

```
vector<Mat> matrices = {
    Mat(4, 1, CV_8UC1, Scalar(1)),
    Mat(4, 1, CV_8UC1, Scalar(2)),
    Mat(4, 1, CV_8UC1, Scalar(3)),
};
Mat R;
hconcat( matrices, R );
cout << R << endl;
```

Here's the result:

```
[1, 2, 3;
  1, 2, 3;
  1, 2, 3;
  1, 2, 3]
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Similarly, if you want to do it vertically (stack by rows), use vconcat.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Mat R(3, 4, CV_32F); // [3 rows x 4 cols] with float values
mat1.copyTo(R.row(0));
mat2.copyTo(R.row(1));
mat3.copyTo(R.row(2));
```

or

```
Mat R(4, 3, CV_32F); // [4 rows x 3 cols] with float values
mat1.copyTo(R.col(0));
mat2.copyTo(R.col(1));
mat3.copyTo(R.col(2));
```

---

Alternatively, as @sub_o suggested, you can also use [`hconcat()/vconcat()`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1368/concatenating-matrices/) to concatenate matrices.

Comment: what to do if mat1 is obtained in a loop and i have to assert in matrix R i.e if loop of 3 we get 3 times value of mat1 and have to assert in R of matrix 4x3.how??

Comment: @user3528954 Do you want to determine the size of `mat1` at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

For those using OpenCv in Python, if you have arrays `A`, `B`, and `C`, and want array `D` that is horizontal concatenation of the others:

```
D = cv2.hconcat((A, B, C))
```

There is also a `vconcat` method.